# Custom 404 in Nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, proxypass

I'm trying to specify a custom 404 page and preserve the URL, however using the below gives me the error `nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in...`

```
location / {
    error_page 404 @404;  
}

location @404 {
   proxy_pass https://example.com/404.html;
}
```

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Why do you need to to use proxy for that `404.html`?

Comment: I want to share the 404 page across different sites/domains/server blocks. I.e I want to use the 404 page from https://www.example.com/404.html for https://test.example.com and other domains using different server blocks.

Comment: I see, because of preserving the URL. If nginx doesn't like named location, try non-existent location: `error_page 404 /404/non-exist; location /404/non-exist { ... }`

Comment: yes, exactly, to preserve the URL. Can you put your code block in an answer please so it's formatted correctly and I can accept it as an answer if it works? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your config on nginx 1.6.2. The error message complains about the URL in `proxy_pass` having *path* specified. Specifying only `https://server` would be OK, but doesn't solve your issue.

Named locations (like `@fallback`) have been introduced also to avoid having to use non-existing locations (which could later become existing and cause issues). But we can also use a location which should never exist on the server itself, for example:

```
location / { error_page 404 /xx-404-xx; }
location /xx-404-xx { proxy_pass https://example.com/404.html; }
```

Redirecting to relative URL causes only internal nginx redirect, which does not change the URL as browser sees it.

**EDIT**: Here is the test result:

```
kenny:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled:# wget -S server.com/abc/abc
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  Server: nginx/1.6.2
  Date: Thu, 16 Jul 2015 07:01:38 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 5
  Connection: keep-alive
  Last-Modified: Thu, 16 Jul 2015 07:00:59 GMT
  ETag: "5037762-5-51af8a241434b"
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
2015-07-16 09:01:38 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

From apache access log:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [16/Jul/2015:09:01:38 +0200] "GET /test.html HTTP/1.0" 200 5 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
```

In nginx I have `proxy_pass` to a html file on Apache webserver with just "test\n" in it. As you can see, nginx fetched that, added headers from Apache (Last-Mod, ETag) and also `Content-Length: 5`, so it received the html file from Apache, but wget doesn't save the content of 404 errors. Also many browsers don't display 404 errors by default if they are smaller than 1 kB (they show their own error page instead). So either make your 404 page bigger or you can configure nginx to serve it as normal html with "200" result code (`error_page 404 =200 /xx`).

I have no idea why you are receiving external redirects with the same config. Try it with `wget` to see which headers exactly nginx sent. Also mixing http and https for proxy should be no issue. Try to remove everything from your config and test only this error page, maybe some other directive is causing this (like other `location` is used instead).

Comment: Thanks! I've just tried it but it redirects me to `https://example.com/404.html/` instead of preserving the URL.

Comment: It works for me (I tried with http instead of https). For test URL I tried both `/xxx` and `/xxx/abc` and both triggered `/404.html` on the remote apache server.

Comment: Hmm, if I use http I get a 301 Moved Permanently nginx page, probably because I'm redirecting http to https. If I use https I get a white page with a message in the top left saying "Redirecting to https://www.example.com/404.html/" then it redirects me to that page.

Comment: I added more info to the answer